# HTTP post/API request works when sent from CURL on bash, fails from Apache http

Tags: java, http, curl, spotify, apache-httpcomponents

I'm trying to use apache http components to interface with the Spotify api. The request I'm trying to send is detailed [here](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#client_credentials_flow) under #1. When I send this request from bash using curl

`curl -H "Authorization: Basic SOMETOKEN" -d grant_type=client_credentials https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token`

I get back a token like the website describes

However the following java code, which as far as I can tell executes the same request, gives back a 400 error

Code

```
    String encoded = "SOMETOKEN";
    CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
        URI auth = new URIBuilder()
                .setScheme("https")
                .setHost("accounts.spotify.com")
                .setPath("/api/token")
                .setParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials")
                .build();

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(auth);
        Header header = new BasicHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
        post.setHeader(header);
        try {
            response = client.execute(post);
            response.getEntity().writeTo(System.out);
        }
        finally {
            response.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Error

> {"error":"server_error","error_description":"Unexpected status: 400"}

The URI that the code prints is looks like this

> https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token?grant_type=client_credentials

And the header looks like this

> Authorization: Basic SOMETOKEN

Am I not constructing the request correctly? Or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use form url-encoding for the data in the body with the content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` :

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();

HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token");
post.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
post.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic " + encoded);
StringEntity data = new StringEntity("grant_type=client_credentials");
post.setEntity(data);

HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

Comment: Thanks! Adding the content type header was all I needed to get the request to go through. Can you explain why I needed that or point me to where I can learn more about what adding that does to the request?

Comment: Because this endpoint expects this specific content-type. When you specified `-d grant_type=client_credentials` with curl you actually use this specific content-type under the hood : see [this](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d)